# Fake SSD or Original?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems

I bought an Apacer SSD 1 TB, but the serial on the sticker is not the same as in Windows 10.

The serial on the sticker: 142207400083 (Apacer site says that is a valid serial)

The Windows serial: 2021121500040 (is invalid).

[Apacer.com - verification site](https://consumer.apacer.com/eng/verification.html)

I used this command to extract this information:

```
wmic diskdrive get model, serialnumber
```

[CMD](https://ibb.co/VpfdgcV)

[SSD](https://ibb.co/Hgv2fQ2)

What else should I check to know for sure that is a fake or original product?

-------------------------------
Edit: more details:

h2test:
https://ibb.co/Gv6LVt5

BIOS:
https://ibb.co/sJ7qFcR

Crystal Disk:
https://ibb.co/g76H9tp

a product that has the same firmware (two different products can have the same fimware?):
https://ibb.co/mNKd12Y

Comment: Why would two products not have the same firmware version?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running some benchmarks and tests, for speed and capacity.

Capacity tests fill the whole thing with data, then read it back (warning that this takes a long time) - a lot of fake drives report the right capacity to windows but can't actually store that much.

And speed tests (both for sustained read/write and random small files) will quickly show if the performance isn't right compared to what you should be getting.

There's a lot of free software out there, and (from my experience) not much difference between them, so the first google results for "SSD capacity test freeware" and "SSD speed test freeware" should do the job (there's no specific software I'd recommend)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).